# How to define multiple graphs with 1 sql-query

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

When i use prometheus (promql) in grafana as datasource i can define a single query that shows multiple graphs on the same panel (e.g. http_requests_total shows all http request). Now i would like to do the same with a sql datasource. I have a table that contains time series data as a simple counter with some tags. i would like to show the counter_value for each tag as a graph. It would work when i define for each tag a single query. But this solution is not really maintainable because the tags can vary. I would prefere to have only 1 query as it works with promql. Is there a way to define a single query that shows for each tag a graph?

In this example only 1 graph is shown. I tried it with group by and my tag column but without success.

```
SELECT
  $__timeGroupAlias(created,24h),
  sum(counter_value) AS "counter_value"
FROM counter
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into [query variables](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/mysql/#query-variable).

Query variables allow you to construct a variable dynamically with an SQL query, which then can be referenced in your dashboard.

You could use a query such as this to obtain all the tag values from your table:

```
SELECT tag FROM counter
GROUP BY tag;
```

I am not 100% sure but it sounds like you may be able to solve your problem by using a query variable to obtain all your desired values, then use the [repeat panel](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/next/panels/repeat-panels-or-rows/) option. The repeat panel option will repeat the graph for each of the variable values. For example, if you have a query variable `tag_var` which returned the values `tag_a, tag_b, tag_c`, you could do something like this with the repeat panel option enabled to repeat on `tag_var`:

```
SELECT
  $__timeGroupAlias(created,24h),
  sum(counter_value) AS "counter_value"
FROM counter
WHERE tag_value = '$tag_var'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it but it's not what i'm looking for. The different tag values are repeated in different pannels. I would like to have the tag values in the same panel with different graphs.

Comment: @sge Have you tried grouping by the tag in your original query? ie. add GROUP BY 1, tag

Comment: it has worked after i updated grafana to the latest version. The pie chart in a previous version didn't show the data correct. thanks